# marker follow polyline when scroll on Google map api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I came to this fantastic site and I would love to know how to create it.
Here is the website:
http://seidenstrasse.srf.ch/de/home.html

Anyone know or can point me on how to move that circle to certain positions in the map following the polyline? Also, how can you do such smooth zooming? I have been searching this answer for days. Any suggestions is appreciated. Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not using google maps api v3 as you seem to believe, its using separate static images from google, called [static image api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/).

Viewing script console reveals that they are coming from address like:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=AIzaSyC6akZWmox8QKHbzRZ5k-K0j4jQx3lM6D0&center=41.297869337699765,32.67865412499997&zoom=4&size=631x223&scale=2&sensor=false&maptype=satellite&format=jpg
```

If it would be normal map from google maps api v3, urls is like the following:

```
https://mts0.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=m@255183771&src=apiv3&hl=en&x=232&y=154&z=8&style=47,37%7Csmartmaps
```

To make something similar you need lots of coding. Here are the steps which you would at least need to make yours similar:

1. Use static image api to fetch images from google and display them as a map in correct positions
2. Take some external library or code yourself those smooth translations between places, because we are dealing with images these can be made with combination of js and css (these moving translations includes the zooming effects, its nothing more than bringing image closer and maybe swiping between to avoid pixels.) Probably from google you find examples how to scale images etc.
3. For markers and polyline, draw them over canvas for example which sits above your static map images. This requires again, more javascript because you need to calculate positions and take use of [requestAnimationFrame](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) for smooth animation. Alternatively, you could use dom elements like images and move them with combination of js and css translations again.

Tbh, this all requires lots of coding and google maps api v3 saves you great deal of work but it wont look so nice, it limits your creativity. Markers can be made move along the lines but it will never look as good as example you provided and it takes more CPU. I have tried those out. I suggest you use google maps api v3 if you are not so experienced with javascript programming and implement marker movement over that.

[Example animation with google maps api v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols#animate)

Answer (score 0):

The linked source is not an implementation of the Maps-Javascript-API(they only use static-map-images as background).

However, animated symbols along a path are possible with the Maps-API, see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols#add_to_polyline